# Upgrade to 5.50.1 failed with "InnoDB refuses to write tables with ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED"

Tags: upgrade

Upgrade to 5.50.1 failed with

[nativecode=4047 ** InnoDB refuses to write tables with ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED or KEY_BLOCK_SIZE.]

It has MariaDB 10.6.5, which sets the innodb_read_only_compressed by default to ON

https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/innodb_read_only_compressed/

Answer (score 1):

To solve this set innodb_read_only_compressed to OFF in my.cnf (or upgrade MariaDB to at least 10.6.6, which sets this value to OFF by default)